# Powershell combine the elements of two arrays into one another

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'd like to join two arrays by picking the elements from each array one by one. and not have them combined or simply merged

I know how to add a second array to the first one as in:

```cs
$array1 = (0,4,8)
$array2 = (1,5,2)
$array1 += $array2
$array1
```

Which results in the following:

```
0
4
8
1
5
2
```

But how can I copy them into one another giving me an output like this:

```
0
1
4
5
8
2
```

**Note**: I don't want to merge them and then sort the list.

The elements need to *stay in the same order*. How would that be achieved?

Comment: Just to clarify; if the arrays are:`$array1 = (0,2,4)` and `$array2 = (5,3,1)`, the expected result is `0 5 2 3 4 1`?

Comment: @iRon yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
$array1 = (0,2,4)
$array2 = (1,3,5)

$MaxLen=[Math]::Max($array1.Length, $array2.Length)

$Result=@()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MaxLen; $i++)
{ 
    $Result+=$array1[$i]
    $Result+=$array2[$i]
}

$Result
```

Answer (score 9):

You can:

1. Place all arrays between parentheses preceded by a dollar sign $( )
2. Seperate all arrays by a semicolon ;

Example:

```
$Array1 = @('a','b')
$Array2 = @('c','d')

$ConcatenatedArray = $($Array1; $Array2) #this is our special line

$ConcatenatedArray
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

We can verify that it is an array with all elements as units and not an array of two arrays, which is the case when you use a coma as separator.

```
$Array1 = @('a','b')
$Array2 = @('c','d')

$ConcatenatedArray = $($Array1; $Array2)

$ConcatenatedArray.Count
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Simple, concise and PowerShell-ish (instead of .NET-ish).

Answer (score 4):

Although Esperento57 gives you a perfect working solution, here's my idea that will also allow for arrays that are not of the same length. It uses a `System.Collections.ArrayList` to add the values from the arrays for better performance if you have large arrays to combine.

```
$array1 = (0,2,4)
$array2 = (1,3,5,6,7,8)

$len1 = $array1.Length
$len2 = $array2.Length
$maxLength = [Math]::Max($len1, $len2)

$listResult = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxLength; $i++) {
    if ($i -lt $len1) { [void] $listResult.Add($array1[$i]) }
    if ($i -lt $len2) { [void] $listResult.Add($array2[$i]) }
}

$listResult.ToArray()
```

Comment: I'm sure this will be handy some day, thank you. I'n my current situation the arrays correlate with each other and have always the same length.

Answer (score 1):

here's another way to do it. [*grin*]

this one takes into account dissimilar sizes in the arrays and interleaves them until one array runs out of items. the remaining items in the larger array are then added without "ghost" items from the the smaller array.

```
$array1 = @(0,2,4)
$array2 = @(5,7,9,11)

$InterleavedArray = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new()

$UpperBound = [math]::Max($array1.GetUpperBound(0), $array2.GetUpperBound(0))

foreach ($Index in 0..$UpperBound)
    {
    if ($Index -le $array1.GetUpperBound(0))
        {
        $InterleavedArray.Add($array1[$Index])
        }
    if ($Index -le $array2.GetUpperBound(0))
        {
        $InterleavedArray.Add($array2[$Index])
        }
    }

$InterleavedArray
```

output ...

```
0
5
2
7
4
9
11
```

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: by changing the [int] to [object] this will also work with text input. thank you.

Comment: @secondplace - yes, the type can be most anything. you are most welcome! glad to have helped! [*grin*] 
take care,

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements to stay in the same order, just do `$array3 = $array1 + $array2`. If you want to sort it though, do `$array3 = ($array1 + $array2) | sort`.

Comment: sorting is not an option as i noted in my first post, i know how to do that. i need the elements copied one after another from each array.

Comment: As a note, what you get is two arrays inside another array. Which may have unintended results if you've combined 2 arrays of 2 strings, you're doing a `foreach` over your new array, and you're expecting to loop through 4 strings. You're going to loop through 2 objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of Theos answer.
Looks cleaner and its faster:

```
$array1 = (0,2,4)
$array2 = (1,3,5,6,7,8)

$len1 = $array1.Length
$len2 = $array2.Length
$maxIndex = [Math]::Max($len1, $len2)-1

$arrayResult = @()
$arrayResult = foreach ($i in 0..$maxIndex) {
    if ($i -lt $len1) { $array1[$i] }
    if ($i -lt $len2) { $array2[$i] }
}
$arrayResult
```